# navigate between pages with JSF

Tags: java, jsf

i want to navigate between pages inside a tab this is my code :

```
<p:tabView id="tabView">

                <p:tab id="tab1" title="Gestion des Utilisateur" titleStyle="titre">

                    <ui:include src="#{directionpage.page}" />
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="tab2" title="Gestion des Equipes">

                   <ui:include src="#{directionpage.page2}" />

                </p:tab>

            </p:tabView>
```

the directionpage jsf managed bean have this variable `String Static page;` and i want change the value of page in other managed beans to navigate to other page. but i am having this error :
The class 'com.jsfmanagedbean.directionpage' does not have a readable property 'page'.

and this is my jsf managed bean

```
package com.jsfmanagedbean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class directionpage {

    public static String page="/admin/gestiondesuser/usergestion.xhtml";
    public static String page2="/admin/gestiondesequipe/gestiondesequipe.xhtml";

    public static String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public static void setPage(String page) {
        directionpage.page = page;
    }

    public static String getPage2() {
        return page2;
    }

    public static void setPage2(String page2) {
        directionpage.page2 = page2;
    }


    public directionpage() {
    }
}
```

i tryed to change the value of page in other managed bean like this :

```
directionpage.page="/admin/gestiondesuser/createuser.xhtml";
```

so how i can change a static value of managedbean from an other managedbean ??

Comment: first of all you could try to follow the conventions on naming. DirectionPage as class name. Then put your variables as private and check if it works.

Answer (score 8):

Your code have some serious problems:

1. Don't use static variables to hold user-specific data. Because when more than one user uses your application, they will be sharing the same static variable as all the static variables are class-scoped , not instance-scoped. Right now your code is not thread-safe.
2. When you try to access your managedBean from the xhtml code, you actually refer to the class instance , not the class itself. JSF follows JavaBean conventions and uses getters/setters of a instance variable to access the instance variables. Because your 'page' variable and its getter/setter methods are class-scoped (static), JSF can not access the mentioned variable. Read about JavaBean conventions and again, dont use static variables.
3. Try to follow Java naming conventions as ojota84 mentioned. Here is a good blog about this: http://blog.sanaulla.info/2008/06/25/camelcase-notation-naming-convention-for-programming-languages/
4. It has some side-effects if your managed beans don't implement Serializable interface. Try to make your beans Serializable.
5. Navigating to other pages by changing a variable in a managed bean is not the perfect way to handle navigation in JSF. I see you're using PrimeFaces so I suggest you to read JSF documentation and PrimeFaces documentation well first. I don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve so I can't say more right now about this issue.

For your current problem, instead use this approach (I didnt test the code):

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class DirectionPage implements Serializable {

    private String page="/admin/gestiondesuser/usergestion.xhtml";
    private String page2="/admin/gestiondesequipe/gestiondesequipe.xhtml";

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public String getPage2() {
        return page2;
    }

    public void setPage2(String page2) {
        this.page2 = page2;
    }


    public directionpage() {
    }
}
```

And you can change the values from another bean like

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class AnotherBean implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty("#{directionPage}")
private DirectionPage directionPage;

  public void setDirectionPage(DirectionPage directionPage) {
     this.directionPage = directionPage;
  }

  public DirectionPage getDirectionPage() {
     return directionPage;
  }

  public void changePage() {
     directionPage.setPage("whateverPage");
  }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ozan i used your code but i get this error : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: the variable isnt changing with directionPage.setPage("whateverPage"); still have same value